# make a mysql connection over an alternate port

Tags: mysql, port, iptables, minecraft

I'm trying to connect to an external mysql database, but port 3306 is already bound on the host hosting my minecraft server, I can change the port that the plugin attempts to connect to, but have no idea how I can redirect another port on the web hosts end to 3306, I've thought about changing the mysql port on the webserver, but have a feeling that this could cause complications...

I don't want to interfere with ANYTHING else that is currently running, just add additional functionality

any suggestions?

also apologies if this is the wrong area to post this, unsure what it would come under.

Comment: Just fond this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056548/iptables-duplicating-forwarding-ports

how do you do a duplicate question response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the port in IPTABLES:
`vi  /etc/sysconfig/iptables`
then look for the line:
`-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`
copy it and change the port to the requested port.
Then edit `vi /etc/my.cnf` and change port `3306` to the new-port.
When you're done, run:

```
service iptables restart
service httpd start
```

Comment: wouldnt I need to insert 2 ports? where does the second port go?

Comment: In case you need to change the existing port - just change `3306` to the requested port. In case you need to leave the port `3306` active - duplicate the line and edit the dup.

Comment: how would the mysql service know how to listen in this case?

I don't want to interfere with ANYTHING else that is currently running, just add additional functionality

Comment: change the port on `vi /etc/my.cnf` from `3306` to the `new-port`