# How to configure CentOS-vServer to support REST Calls on domain-name running Spring Boot on Port 8080

Tags: html, spring, rest, spring-boot, centos7

i have the domain www.abc.com registered and forwarded via DNS-A-Record to my vServer 111.222.333.444 running CentOS 7.

I have a jar-File containing a fully working Spring-Boot Application answering REST Calls on Port 8080.

The Problem is, whatever I do, i can't manage to make it work.

I want to do this:

www.abc.com/status or www.abc.com:8080/status to get a response

it works locally with localhost:8080/status but not from outside via my domain.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access www.abc.com/status the you have to run the application on port 80 or add a reverse proxy like nginx or Apache HTTP server in-front of your application.

If you cannot access www.abc.com:8080/status you should check if there are any firewall settings that don't allow access to port 8080 resp. only allow access to port 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

You can use port forwarding on your machine using iptables.
it is explained in other posts e.g here:
[iptables: Duplicating/Forwarding ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056548/iptables-duplicating-forwarding-ports)

Simon's observation regarding to firewall is correct for this solution too.